# Starting Point Hackthebox Error "Your port specifications are illegal"

Tags: nmap

I'm trying to scan the ports on the "Starting Point" CHallenge from Hackthebox.

- i downloaded the .ovpn and established the vpn connnection in my Kali VM
- typed in:
  `ports=$(nmap -p- --min-rate=1000 -T4 10.10.10.27 | grep ^[0-9] | cut -d '/' -f 1 | tr '\n' ',' | sed s/,$//)`

but when i try
`nmap -sC -sV -p$ports 10.10.10.27`
I get the error message that my port specifications are illegal.

Happy for every help i can get!

Answer (score 0):

My nmap scans worked on the first try. When I restarted my machine on another day, I had the same issue.

Re-download the connection pack.

This worked for me.